# Find limit of quite complex function

Tags: analysis, limits

Tomorrow I have an exam on mathematical analysis and I solving exams task from earlier years, and here is:

> Find limit of:
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(4n^3 + 1)(4n - 2)!n\sin{\frac{2}{n}}}{(4n + 1)!+3} $$

I checked in Wolfram Alpha and Maxima that it is $\frac{1}{8}$ but how to get this? I have tried almost everything I remember but still cannot find solution.

<sub>Firstly, sorry for the title, but I have no idea how to describe this shorter.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: convince yourself that the $3$ in the denominator can safely be ignored.

Step 2: deal with the $n\sin(2/n)$ as one piece, and with the rest of it as another.